# how to add a rich text license to a dmg using a plist with javafx?

Tags: macos, javafx-2, dmg

All the JavaFX [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm#BCGIBBCI) say is:
The DMG installer also supports a click-though license provided in the text format. If use of rich text format is desired, then prepare the license.plist file externally, then add it to the package using the technique from Section 6.3.3, "Customization Using Drop-In Resources."

Surprisingly, I couldn't find anywhere on the internet how to actually accomplish this. Did anyone here succeed in creating a dmg with a rich text license?
I also posted my question [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2536416) btw.

Before you reply with [attach license file to dmg under OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970981/attach-license-file-to-dmg-under-osx), that is only for a plain text file, which I already know how to do.