# JavaFx - License is not displaying in proper format

Tags: javafx

I implemented the javafx standalone app. I provided the **.rtf** file for license. It shows properly in windows but in Mac, the format was changed please refer the following image. Why? How do we fix it?

```
Code
```

< project name="shore-abs" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">
    Builds, tests, and runs the project shore-abs.

```
<target name="-pre-jfx-jar" depends="copy-build-properties" />

<target name="copy-build-properties" >
    <copy file="config${file.separator}abs-client-build.properties" 
          todir="${basedir}${file.separator}${build.classes.dir}${file.separator}/config" />
</target>
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy" depends="-check-jfx-deployment">
    <fx:application id="abs-client" name="${application.title}" 
                    mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"/>

    <fx:deploy width="100" height="100" includeDT="false"
               nativeBundles="all"
               embeddedWidth="100%" embeddedHeight="100%"
               outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" embedJNLP="true"
               outfile="${application.title}" verbose="true">
        <fx:application refId="abs-client"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="shore-abs.jar"/>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="lib/**"/>
            <fx:fileset type="license" dir="${basedir}" includes="license.rtf"/>
        </fx:resources> 
        <fx:info title="${application.title}"
                 vendor="${application.vendor}"/>
    </fx:deploy>
< /target>
```

< /project>

[image: License in Mac]

Comment: Could you show me the source code of the window? I would like to see ho do you display the text.

Comment: @PeterPenzov: i didn't understand what you are asking. you mean license file content or windows license image?

Comment: Can you show us the source code.

Comment: This question is similar to [how to add a rich text license to a dmg using JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616075/how-to-add-a-rich-text-license-to-a-dmg-using-a-plist-with-javafx)

Comment: According to the Oracle documentation only Windows uses rtf while OSX uses plain text files.http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference002.htm#CIAIHFGI